# Scrapy not following links in domain

Tags: python, scrapy

Cant understand why crawlspider finishes crawling at the `start_urls` link for website cvvp.nva.gov.lv/#/pub/. The `parse_item` code is just to test if the spider is following other links within the `allowed_domain`. Seems its not following other links. I tried the exact code by changing `allowed_domains = ['books.toscrape.com']` and `start_urls = ['https://books.toscrape.com']` and it worked fine.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
class CvspiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'cvspider'
    allowed_domains = ['cvvp.nva.gov.lv']
    start_urls = ['https://cvvp.nva.gov.lv/#/pub/']
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )
    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = {}
        print('success')
        return item
```

Im not getting any errors either. Heres the console

```
2021-09-02 16:11:38 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2021-09-02 16:11:38 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2021-09-02 16:11:38 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2021-09-02 16:11:38 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://cvvp.nva.gov.lv/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2021-09-02 16:11:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://cvvp.nva.gov.lv/#/pub/> (referer: None)
2021-09-02 16:11:43 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

There is no robots.txt file and request headers are set to `'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36 Edg/92.0.902.84'`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem lies in some fact that the whole site is in javascript. If javascript is disabled than there is no content